# Show this error when you click on sidebar item “undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')” react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, native-base

[react-navigation error img.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKGNb.png)
I am using react-navigation in my app. Tried to do some test with -native-base side bar. and when you click on the any nav item inside side bar it shows this error. How can it be solved for this side bar?  Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, ScrollView,Button,Text,StyleSheet,Dimensions } from "react-native";
import {Container,Content,List,Icon,Badge,ListItem,Left,Right,Body} from 'native-base'
import Exponent from 'expo'


import { DrawerItems } from 'react-navigation';
const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const datas = [
    {
        name: "Home",
        route: "HomeScreen",
        icon: "phone-portrait",
        bg: "#C5F442",
    },
    {
        name: "Business",
        route: "Business",
        icon: "easel",
        bg: "#C5F442",
    },
    {
        name: "Education",
        route: "Education",
        icon: "phone-portrait",
        bg: "#477EEA",
        types: "8",
    },
    {
        name: "Life Style",
        route: "Lifestyle",
        icon: "phone-portrait",
        bg: "#DA4437",
        types: "4",
    },
    {
        name: "Tech",
        route: "Tech",
        icon: "notifications",
        bg: "#4DCAE0",
    },
    {
        name: "Contact",
        route: "Contact",
        icon: "radio-button-off",
        bg: "#1EBC7C",
        types: "9",
    },]


const  DrawerContent = (props) => {

  let showItems = props.items.filter(itemObj => {
    return itemObj.routeName !== 'Welcome'
      && itemObj.routeName !== 'Signin'
      && itemObj.routeName !== 'Signup'
  })


  return (
    <View style={style.container}>
    <Content>
    <List
          dataArray={datas}
          renderRow={data =>
            <ListItem button noBorder onPress={() =>  this.props.navigation.navigate(data.route)}>
              <Left>
                <Icon active name={data.icon} style={{ color: "#777", fontSize: 26, width: 30 }} />
                <Text>
                  {data.name}
                </Text>
              </Left>
              {data.types &&
                <Right style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                  <Badge
                    style={{
                      borderRadius: 3,
                      height: 25,
                      width: 72,
                      backgroundColor: data.bg,
                    }}
                  >
                    <Text>{`${data.types} Types`}</Text>
                  </Badge>
                </Right>}
            </ListItem>}
        />
      </Content>


    </View>
  )
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {

    height: screenHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#494949',
    flex:1,
    paddingTop: Exponent.Constants.statusBarHeight,

  },
});

export default DrawerContent;
```

Is there any solution for this error and for this code?

Comment: Please try changing `this.props.navigation.navigate(data.route)` to `props.navigation.navigate(data.route)`

Comment: is this your sidebar file ?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the similar problem ,use it like this

In your class where you are using sidebar class declare a function for navigation

```
goto(route) {
        console.log("navigation" + route);
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        navigate(route);
    }
```

Then bind this function to the side bar

```
content={<DrawerContent route={this.goto.bind(this)} />} >
```

Then in sidebar file handle on press like this

```
onPress={() => this.props.route('Page Name')}
```